# How to create a "connect the dot" style map in react with canvas?

Tags: reactjs, svg, html5-canvas

I need to create a "connect the dot" style react component which displays a "map" of dots connected by a "path" advancing through different stages, according to some data defined in a JSON. My problem is not with the programming logic, but how should I draw it, either with html canvas,css,svg or a combination of both:

[image]

I already have a component ready with the background, but I don't know how to draw the dots:

[image]

Some code:

```js
class MapCanvas extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classNames("exams-map-canvas", this.props.stage)}> 
            </div>
        );
    }



}
```

```css
.exams-map-canvas {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    height: 100%;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;



    @media (min-width: 700px) {
        & {
            top: 15%;
            height: 550px;
        }
    }
    
    // Large screen
    @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
        & {
            height: 550px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1400px) {
        & {
            height: 650px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1700px) {
        & {
            height: 850px;
        }
    }
```

How can I add dots connected by lines to this?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://www.formerspatial.com/polygonanimations, there is an example with a "connecting the dots", the code is here: https://github.com/willymaps/animation/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use SVG to draw on top of the image. It maps very well with JSX and its quite powerful.

Here is my take on how you could build your components:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/connect-the-dot-style-map-5d7nm

On the example, I took the liberty of modifying the style of the nodes and the links if they were "done".

One thing, whatever you choose to draw on the page, look at the `d3` library. It has a ton of helper functions to create designs online. On my example, I am using the `d3-scale` module to create a scale to map from an arbitrary 0-100 domain to the width and height of the image. Now you can store the relative location of the dots, and adapt them to any map's width and height. You can also play with the SVG `viewPort` to handle how much to show.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, The only thing I need to figure out is how to use it with my component which has a dynamic height and width(according to screen size). Any suggestions?

Comment: I have done something similar to what you need on [this link](https://github.com/conatel-i-d/cri/blob/master/dashboard/src/common/ResponsiveContainer/ResponsiveContainer.js). Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The shared link was inside a private repo. I'll pas it as a gist soon.

Comment: On [this link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/responsivewrapper-c8ncx) you'll find an example of how you can pass the width and height of the parent component to the child. I use `react-measure` on this example, though there are other libraries that can also help.

Comment: Thanks alot. Do you have any idea also on how to insert a font awesome icon into that gray svg circle?

Comment: Every `font-awesome` icon is defined as an `svg`. So you could insert it along the circles and lines. Use a `<g></g>` tag to insert the components that compose the icon (ussually `<path></path>), and `translate` and `scale` that group using transforms to locate it where you need. Have a look at the following link for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Answer (score 0):

```js
class MapCanvas extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classNames("exams-map-canvas", this.props.stage)}> 
            </div>
        );
    }



}
```

```css
.exams-map-canvas {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    height: 100%;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;



    @media (min-width: 700px) {
        & {
            top: 15%;
            height: 550px;
        }
    }
    
    // Large screen
    @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
        & {
            height: 550px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1400px) {
        & {
            height: 650px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1700px) {
        & {
            height: 850px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).